# Are files saved anywhere in server disk when submit a form with files (ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post" action="@Url.Action( "Test" )">
   <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

and in server side (using ASP.NET MVC controller):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test( HttpPostedFileBase[] files )
{
    // and here save some files, not all.
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

when I make submit, are files stored in temporary folder or in memory ?

For example, I want to upload 8 files and server side I want to filter these files by a criteria. Does these files are saved on disk or not ?

Comment: Until you not save them in code they are not saved

Comment: What's about 100MB file(s) ? Where are stored ? In memory ?

Comment: until you get them from Request object and save it on disk it will not be saved, it will just be on the disk of client

Answer (score 0):

Until you write code and execute to save, the file will not be saved / processed to save.

It will be allowed to store when you save the file. Until otherwise it will be in the  `files` object. Once you out of `Test()` function, the object will be erased. Its not mean that file will be loaded to `temp / some where in the server`. It will be an request object. When you do operation it will be uploaded from client to server.

You are doing an operation over the `Http / https`. Not with in a machine.

To Get better understand when you click on upload - Just open `Developer` tools / Press F12 in Browser and Go to `Network Tab`.

[image: Posted file from client to server - Upload]

Check the posted / Uploaded file request demo here [Click Here](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/)

Comment: I thought the same thing, yet when enabling read-only file system, it does seem to store it 'somewhere': `"Failed to read the request form. Read-only file system`